# GridControl in usercontrol refresh from other usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls, devexpress

I'm trying to refresh my GridControl after I made changes to the database. The changes are saved in the database, but the GridControl doesn't show the new data. How to refresh the grid and show the changes which are made in the database? The MessageBox in the update method is to check if the method is executed and the MessageBox pops up so it's executed.

Part of the class with the GridControl

```
public partial class incidentCategorySearchControl : UserControl
{
    public static incidentCategorySearchControl Instance { get; set; }


    public incidentCategorySearchControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;

        // This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
        incIncidentCategoryTableAdapter1.Fill(reinvenT_QualityDataSet1.IncIncidentCategory);
    }

    public void updateGridControl()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("..........." );
        //categoryGridControl.RefreshDataSource();
        incIncidentCategoryTableAdapter1.Fill(reinvenT_QualityDataSet1.IncIncidentCategory);


    }
}
```

Part of the class where the GridControl update method is called:

```
 private void saveCategoryChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Opslaan mislukt controleer a.u.b. of alle verplichte velden juist zijn ingevuld");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlServerConnection.sqlConnection.ConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE IncIncidentCategory SET IncIncidentCatDescription = @categoryDescription WHERE IncIncidentCategory = @categoryId", con))
                    {
                        IncidentCategory incidentCategoryUpdate = new IncidentCategory(Convert.ToInt32(incidentCategoryTextBox.Text), incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Text);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryId", incidentCategoryUpdate._categoryId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryDescription", incidentCategoryUpdate._description);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Wijzigingen opgeslagen"); 

                    }
                }

                incidentTypeChange.Instance.refreshCategorySearchBox();
                incidentTypeMaintenance.Instance.refreshCategorySearchBox();
                incidentCategorySearchControl.Instance.updateGridControl(); // update doesn't work 
                //var control = new incidentCategorySearchControl();
                //control.updateDataGridView();



            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Voer voor beide velden geldige waarden in a.u.b.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What class is `incIncidentCategoryTableAdapter1`?

Comment: It's an auto created table adapter, created when I set up the GriddControl datasource by using the GridControl datasource wizard.